# How to determine which plugin in missing from a NEW build of Intellij-Community?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've just compiled, built and run Intellij-Community with the IDEA configuration file and it aborts, it looks like it's missing a plugin.  How to resolve this?

Here's most of the log:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java" -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=150m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Xbootclasspath/p:../out/classes/production/boot -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -Dsun.awt.disablegrab=true -Didea.is.internal=true -Didea.debug.mode=true -Didea.config.path=../config -Didea.system.path=../system -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\lib\tools.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\annotations;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\annotations-common;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\ant;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\openapi;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\util;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jdom.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\log4j.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\trove4j.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\picocontainer.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\platform-resources-en;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\util-rt;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jna.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jna-platform.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\oromatcher.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jsr166e.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\snappy-in-java-0.3.1.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\imgscalr-lib-4.2.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\batik-all.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\xml-apis-ext.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\forms_rt;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\extensions;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\xstream-1.4.8.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\icons;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\microba.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jgoodies-forms.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xml-openapi;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\lang-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\platform-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\core-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\automaton.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\asm.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\asm-commons.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\cglib-2.2.2.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\bootstrap;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\projectModel-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\jps-model-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\netty-all-4.1.0.Beta8.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\proxy-vole_20131209.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\analysis-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\editor-ui-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\indexing-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\pty4j-0.6.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\guava-17.0.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\httpcore-4.4.1.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\httpmime-4.4.1.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\httpclient-4.4.1.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\fluent-hc-4.4.1.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\lvcs-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xml-psi-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xml-analysis-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xml-structure-view-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\vcs-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\vcs-api-core;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\diff-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\xmlrpc-2.0.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\dom-openapi;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\platform-resources;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\lvcs-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\vcs-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\platform-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\boot;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jh.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\winp-1.23.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\swingx-core-1.6.2.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\core-impl;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-runtime.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-reflect.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\miglayout-swing.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\indexing-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\projectModel-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\jps-model-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\jps-model-serialization;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\sanselan-0.98-snapshot.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\analysis-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\resources-en;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\editor-ui-ex;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jayatana-1.2.4.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\gson-2.5.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\built-in-server;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xdebugger-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\built-in-server-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\configuration-store-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\lang-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\velocity.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\usageView;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\xpp3-1.1.4-min.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\cli-parser-1.1.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\structure-view-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\diff-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jcip-annotations.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\json;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\spellchecker;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\xercesImpl.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\xml-apis.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xml;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jsr173_1.0_api.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\xbean.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\resolver.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xml-psi-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\RegExpSupport;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jaxen-1.1.3.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\dom-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\relaxng;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\xml\relaxng\lib\rngom-20051226-patched.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\xml\relaxng\lib\isorelax.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\xml\relaxng\lib\trang-core.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\xml\relaxng\lib\jing.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xdebugger-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xml-analysis-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xml-structure-view-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\java-psi-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\java-indexing-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\java-analysis-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-commons-net.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-jmf.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-apache-resolver.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-jai.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-apache-bsf.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-commons-logging.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-junit.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-jsch.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-apache-bcel.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-netrexx.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-apache-oro.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-antlr.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-jdepend.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-launcher.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-apache-regexp.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-apache-log4j.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-swing.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\ant\lib\ant-javamail.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\compiler-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\compiler-openapi;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\java-runtime;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\instrumentation-util;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\asm-all.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\jsp-openapi;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\jsp-base-openapi;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\java-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\jsp-spi;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\execution-openapi;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\resources;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\images;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\community-resources;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\groovy-all-2.3.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\java-psi-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\java-indexing-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\java-analysis-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\external-system-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\external-system-rt;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\java-structure-view;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\nekohtml-1.9.14.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\jps-builders;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\forms-compiler;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\protobuf-2.5.0.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\jps\lib\optimizedFileManager.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\jps-launcher;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\execution-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\debugger-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\debugger-openapi;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\testRunner;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\smRunner;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\serviceMessages.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\coverage-agent.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\coverage-instrumenter.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\coverage-util.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\properties;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\properties-psi-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\properties-psi-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\idea-ui;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\ant-jps-plugin;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\commander;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\platform-main;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\testFramework;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\junit-4.12.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\tests_bootstrap;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\testFramework-java;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\external-system-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\java-i18n;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\IntelliLang-java;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\IntelliLang;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\IntelliLang-xml;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xpath;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xslt-rt;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\copyright;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\cvs-plugin;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\cvs-core;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\javacvs-src;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\cvs\lib\trilead-ssh2-build213.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\smartcvs-src;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\ui-designer;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\devkit;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\devkit\lib\dtdparser113.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\devkit-jps-plugin;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\eclipse;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\eclipse-jps-plugin;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\common-eclipse-util;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\git4idea;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\git4idea\lib\trilead-ssh2.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\git4idea-rt;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\git4idea\lib\ini4j\ini4j-0.5.2-patched.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\dvcs-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\vcs-log-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\vcs-log-graph-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\vcs-log-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\vcs-log-graph;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\dvcs-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jsch-0.1.52.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\jetgroovy;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\groovy_rt;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\groovy-rt-constants;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\groovy-jps-plugin;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\ByteCodeViewer;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\groovy-psi;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\junit;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\junit.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\junit_rt;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\maven;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\maven-server-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven-server-api\lib\lucene-core-2.4.1.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\lib\wadl-core.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jaxb-api.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jaxb-impl.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\maven2-server-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven2-server-impl\lib\plexus-utils-1.5.5.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven2-server-impl\lib\maven-dependency-tree-1.2.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven2-server-impl\lib\archetype-common-2.0-alpha-4-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven2-server-impl\lib\mercury-artifact-1.0-alpha-6.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven2-server-impl\lib\maven2\lib\maven-2.2.1-uber.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven2-server-impl\lib\maven2\boot\classworlds-1.1.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven2-server-impl\lib\nexus-indexer-1.2.3.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven2-server-impl\lib\activation-1.1.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven2-server-impl\lib\commons-beanutils.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\maven-jps-plugin;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\lib\plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\maven-artifact-resolver-m2;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\maven-artifact-resolver-common;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\maven-artifact-resolver-m3;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven30-server-impl\lib\maven3\lib\aether-api-1.13.1.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven30-server-impl\lib\maven3\lib\maven-core-3.0.5.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven30-server-impl\lib\maven3\lib\maven-artifact-3.0.5.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\maven30-server-impl\lib\maven3\lib\plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\maven-artifact-resolver-m31;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\artifact-resolver-m31\lib\eclipse-aether\aether-api-0.9.0.M2.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\maven\lib\plexus-archiver-2.4.4.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\svn4idea;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\svn4idea\lib\svnkit.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\svn4idea\lib\trilead.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\svn4idea\lib\sequence-library.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\svn4idea\lib\sqljet.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\svn4idea\lib\antlr.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\svn4idea\lib\svnkit-javahl.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\purejavacomm.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jsch.agentproxy.usocket-nc.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jsch.agentproxy.sshagent.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jsch.agentproxy.pageant.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jsch.agentproxy.core.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\jsch.agentproxy.connector-factory.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\svn4idea\lib\jsch.agentproxy.svnkit-trilead-ssh2.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\testng;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\testng_rt;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\testng\lib\testng.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\testng\lib\jcommander.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\typeMigration;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\structuralsearch;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\duplicates-analysis;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\structuralsearch-java;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xslt-debugger;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\xslt-debugger-engine;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\xslt-debugger\engine\lib\rmi-stubs.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\tasks-core;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\tasks-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1-patched.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\tasks\tasks-core\lib\axis-1.4.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\tasks\tasks-core\lib\axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\tasks\tasks-core\lib\wsdl4j-1.4.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\tasks\tasks-core\lib\axis-saaj-1.3.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\tasks\tasks-core\lib\json-path-0.8.0.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\tasks\tasks-core\lib\json-smart-1.1.1.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\tasks\tasks-core\lib\commons-discovery-0.4.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\markdownj-core-0.4.2-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\tasks-java;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\github;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\hg4idea;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\gradle;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\gradle-tooling-extension-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle-tooling-api-2.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle-core-2.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle-messaging-2.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle-wrapper-2.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle-base-services-2.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle-base-services-groovy-2.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle-native-2.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\gradle-tooling-extension-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle-model-core-2.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle-model-groovy-2.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\guava-jdk5-17.0.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\gradle-jps-plugin;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle-resources-2.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\gradle-cli-2.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\commons-io-1.4.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\jna-3.2.7.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\gradle\lib\native-platform-0.10.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\minlog-1.2.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\kryo-2.22.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\reflectasm-1.07.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\lib\objenesis-1.2.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\remote-servers-impl;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\remote-servers-api;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\remote-servers-agent-rt;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\colorSchemes;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\javaFX-CE;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\javaFX;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\common-javaFX-plugin;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\manifest;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\javaFX\lib\SceneBuilderKit-8.1.1.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\javaFX-jps-plugin;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\yaml;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\jira;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\java-decompiler-plugin;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\java-decompiler-engine;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\structuralsearch-groovy;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\coverage;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\coverage-common;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\coverage\lib\coverage-report.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\coverage\lib\coverage-report-idea.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\coverage\lib\freemarker.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\coverage\lib\jacocoant.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\coverage\lib\jacocoagent.jar;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\coverage_rt;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\remote-servers-git-java;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\remote-servers-git;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\out\production\terminal;C:\AAAIntellij\Intellij-Community\plugins\terminal\lib\jediterm-pty-2.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.idea.Main
[  14956]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.getInstance(ProgressManager.java:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.AbstractProgressIndicatorBase.(AbstractProgressIndicatorBase.java:38)
    at com.intellij.ide.customize.CustomizeFeaturedPluginsStepPanel.onPluginGroupsLoaded(CustomizeFeaturedPluginsStepPanel.java:142)
    at com.intellij.ide.customize.CustomizeFeaturedPluginsStepPanel.access$000(CustomizeFeaturedPluginsStepPanel.java:49)
    at com.intellij.ide.customize.CustomizeFeaturedPluginsStepPanel$1.run(CustomizeFeaturedPluginsStepPanel.java:64)
    at com.intellij.ide.customize.PluginGroups$1.done(PluginGroups.java:73)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(SwingWorker.java:737)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(SwingWorker.java:832)
    at sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(AccumulativeRunnable.java:112)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(SwingWorker.java:842)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:313)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:245)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:367)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:792)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:465)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1661)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1610)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.runStartupWizard(StartupUtil.java:420)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:44)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'componentManager' of com/intellij/openapi/components/ServiceManager.doGetService must not be null
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.doGetService(ServiceManager.java)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:37)

[  14970]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition) IC-146.SNAPSHOT  Build #IC-146.SNAPSHOT 
[  14970]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_45 
[  14970]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[  14970]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[  14970]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 7

Start Failed: Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'componentManager' of com/intellij/openapi/components/ServiceManager.doGetService must not be null
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.doGetService(ServiceManager.java)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0

Process finished with exit code 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen that error before, and it's related to an internal bug, nothing you can do about it, your options are:

1. Change the JDK version or
2. Change the Intellij version

Is that the last version of IntelliJ? And I bet it is the 64 bit version, I have only seen that error for the 64 bit version for Windows. So maybe using the latest version of IntelliJ or even trying with the 32bit version might help.
I see you are using JDK 1.8.0_45, maybe updating to the latest version could be good too.

Comment: Reading the stacktrace I see that there is no dependency missing, It's a `null` in the Plugin Manager `com.intellij.idea.Main [ 14956] ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null `